# I can't dispatch event in Alpinejs

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, alpine.js

I am using Laravel 8, Alpinejs and Livewire and having this problem:
This is my index file:

```html
@extends('dashboard')

@section('content')
    <header class="max-w-7xl mx-auto bg-white flex items-center justify-between">
        <div class="mx-9 py-6 mt-4">
            <h1 class="text-3xl font-bold text-gray-900">
                Boards
            </h1>
        </div>
        <div class="mx-9 py-6 mt-4">
            <a href="#" @click="
                        $dispatch('custom-event')
                    "
                class="w-28 text-base text-white bg-blue hover:text-gray-50 hover:bg-blue-hover rounded-xl py-2 px-3 leading-none transition ease-in duration-150 text-center">
                Create new board
            </a>
        </div>
    </header>

    <livewire:boards-table
        :boards="$boards"
    />
    <livewire:create-board />
@endsection
```

When I click the "Create new board" button in the header tag, I want the create-board livewire component to be displayed. So I used `@click="$dispatch('custom-event')`.
And here is my create-board file:

```html
<div
    x-cloak
    x-data="{ isOpen: false }"
    x-show="isOpen"
    @keydown.escape.window="isOpen = false"
    @custom-event.window="isOpen = true"

    class="fixed z-20 inset-0 overflow-y-auto"
    aria-labelledby="modal-title"
    role="dialog"
    aria-modal="true"
>
    <div class="flex items-end justify-center min-h-screen">
        <div x-show.transition.opacity="isOpen" class="fixed inset-0 bg-gray-500 bg-opacity-75 transition-opacity"
            aria-hidden="true">
        </div>

        <div x-show.transition.origin.bottom.duration.300ms="isOpen"
            class="modal bg-white rounded-tl-xl rounded-tr-xl overflow-hidden transform transition-all sm:max-w-lg sm:w-full">
            <div class="absolute top-0 right-0 pt-6 pr-6">
                <button @click="isOpen = false" class="text-gray-400 hover:text-gray-500">
                    <svg class="h-5 w-5" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor">
                        <path fill-rule="evenodd"
                            d="M4.293 4.293a1 1 0 011.414 0L10 8.586l4.293-4.293a1 1 0 111.414 1.414L11.414 10l4.293 4.293a1 1 0 01-1.414 1.414L10 11.414l-4.293 4.293a1 1 0 01-1.414-1.414L8.586 10 4.293 5.707a1 1 0 010-1.414z"
                            clip-rule="evenodd" />
                    </svg>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="bg-white sm:p-6 my-3">
                <h3 class="text-center text-xl font-bold text-gray-900">Create a new board</h3>

                <form wire:submit.prevent="createBoard" action="#" method="POST" class="space-y-4 px-4 pt-6">
                    <div>
                        <input wire:model.defer="boardName" type="text"
                            class="w-full bg-gray-100 rounded-xl placeholder-gray-900 border-none font-semibold px-4 text-sm"
                            placeholder="Board name">
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <input wire:model.defer="urlName" type="text"
                            class="w-full bg-gray-100 rounded-xl placeholder-gray-900 border-none font-semibold px-4 py-2 text-sm"
                            placeholder="Short name (used in board URL)">
                    </div>
                    <div class="flex items-center justify-end">
                        <button type="submit"
                            class="text-center w-44 bg-blue font-bold h-11 text-sm text-white rounded-xl border border-blue hover:bg-blue-hover transition duration-150 ease-in px-6 py-3 mr-4 mt-2">Create new board</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But when I click on "Create new board" button, nothing happens.
Create-board component is still rendered in the browser.

Comment: I solved this problem by adding x-data to the div containing the a tag. It took me half a day!!